# Is it possible to attach a derived class using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've googled to no avail, so assume that it is not possible to call `Attach()` on class derived from an entity model using Entity Framework (6)? I'm using the 'Database first' approach.

For example, inserting the class `Dog` as follows:

```
public partial class Animal //this will insert fine.
{
   public long AnimalId
}

public class Dog:Animal //this will not insert.
{
}
```

I'm currently getting the error:

> The entity type Dog is not part of the model for the current context.

Full code:

```
           public class Dog : Animal
           {
           }

            using (var context = new CalibrationManagerEntities())
            {
                var a = new Animal() { AnimalId = 0 };
                var b = context.Entry(a); //works

                var c = new Dog() { AnimalId = 0 };
                var d = context.Entry(c); //throws exception
            }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Show the full code please.

Comment: @GertArnold updated

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear. The context doesn't know `Dog`.

Comment: Dog is not present in your DbContext metadata. You should make sure that DbSet<Dog> exist in your context or just configure a TPH, TPT etc  between Animal and Dog.

Comment: Is there any way to map the `Dog` to `Animal`?

Comment: Make them share the same table, separate table etc.. by using [TPH, TPT, ..](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Comment: What's the real world scenario? Dog sounds like ViewModel or something like that to me. If yes, don't use inheritance, do use containment instead. (and yes, it's not possible to `Attach`, `Add` etc. derived class which is not part of the entity model).

Answer (score -2):

Casting the dog as Animal should do the trick

```
context.Attach((Animal)dog)
```

Comment: That doesn't make make any difference